# jQuery not changing CSS even though element found in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

Apologies in advance if this question is unclear; I'm pretty new.

I am working on a Chrome extension to change the color of most viewed headlines on www.nytimes.com. My issue is that I can't get jQuery to reliably override the CSS on a page.

I am using a function to search all the anchors on the page, comparing the text of those anchors to an array of titles, and modifying the CSS if the text matches one of the titles. Here's what I have:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($.inArray($this.text(), titles) !== -1) {
      console.log("found title");
      $this.css('color', color);
    }
  });
```

The console.log statement is for testing, and it is indeed showing me that I'm finding 8 matches on my page at the moment. However, only four of the matches are getting the CSS color applied. The four titles that get changed are all in the "most emailed" section of the page. The corresponding titles in the main body of the page do not get changed, even though the text of the headlines is identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: So, as I mentioned in another response, the final line to change CSS is working fine. I am using a variable for color and passing in a string. I can change it to "red", "#006600" or whatever, it still only changes half the headlines.

Comment: I am noticing in the html that in the main article, there may be a newline before the text in the anchor tags that I am not picking up. I have searched, but it does not appear you can add a regex to $.inArray (and I wouldn't know how to do so if you could). Could that be it?

Comment: try making the new override to color !important

Comment: try comparing the links instead of the text on the titles

Comment: you are comapring .text() ,it must be an exact match,or process the text with trim() or other string formatters before comparing.

Comment: Thank you! Adding .trim() worked great, I wasn't aware I could do that without a complicated regex. Not sure how to mark as correct, can you post this as an answer and then I mark it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h00rkdpn/3/) here ,

`$this.css('color', 'red');`

and use .trim() for exact string comparisons,

```
$this.text().trim()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, very simple solution now that I see it!

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line

```
$this.css('color', color);
```

to

```
$this.css({color:'#006600'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That line works as well (from my research, you can use either format to change the css). Still just changes only half the titles. In case it's not clear, I have color defined as a variable and I'm passing in a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .css file. If that file contains something like follows for your text:

```
someSelector {
 ... 
  ...
 color: "somecolor !important ";
 ...
```

}

Then jQuery can't override it via code. Please modify your css file first and then try setting it with code.